# Control pgf/tikz semilog factor

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm currently using the `semilogy` environment and wondering on how to control whether they actually take `10 log` or `20 log`.

Comment: The option `log basis y=20` might be related. But I am unsure of what you mean by "actually take". Could you write a minimal working example and more details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Assuming I have some data x, I want to plot either 10*log10(x) or 20*log10(x). When I read through your manual of pgf, I thought that the 'log basis' command handles whether it takes natural logarithm or dual logarithm etc, but not the multiplier. Please see also my first try( answer)  maybe this clarifies what I mean.

Comment: Ok. In this case, `y filter` is what you need. But the input argument to `y filter` already has the log applied (namely the one defined by `log basis y` which is `e` by default). Consequently, you would need `\pgfmathparse{20*\pgfmathresult}` since `\pgfmathresult` already contains `log_b(y)`. The result appears to be useless, though: `20*log(y) = log(y^20)`. If `y=10^{-5}` and `log basis y=10`, you receive `20*log(y) =-100` which corresponds to a value `10^{-100}`. Is this what you want!?

Comment: But does it always include the logarithm or only when I'm in semilogy environment? Because I tried to apply the filter without logarithm, just as you said, to the semilogy environment and it seems that the filter is applied before taking the logarithm which gives a different result.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger sorry, please ignore my previous comment. I was in a rush and havent read your comment correctly.Yes this is exactly what I want! and If I do it as you propose, I can stay with 'semiglogy' environment, right? Does this have any advantage over applying my 'fix' to the 'axis' environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach to rely on `y filter` is correct in this case. However, it operates on different values depending on whether you have a log axis or a linear one: a log axis provides the log of the value as input to `y filter`. Since you explicitly want a log basis 10, you need to specify `log basis y=10` for a log axis (otherwise you'll have log basis e).

The difference between a linear axis with a filter which applies log and a log axis which multiplies values by 20 is just in the axis descriptions.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[
        y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{20*log10(\pgfmathresult)}},
    ]
    {10^x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        log basis y=10,
        ytickten={-100,-50,...,100},
    ]
    \addplot+[
        y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{20*\pgfmathresult}},
    ]
    {10^x};
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My own solutions as style for the normal `axis` environment:

```
every axis plot/.style={ y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{20*log10(\pgfmathresult)}\pgfmathresult} },
```

Comment: It seems as if this is actually part of the question. In this case, you should put your remark into the question and state some thing like "from what I understood, this here should do the job but it doesn't" and ask for help. If you post an answer (as here), others will assume that the question is answered and you just wanted to share your insight. In addition, it will significantly help if you add a complete minimal working example to your question.

Comment: Ok, this is really what you wanted achieve. You should eliminate the final `\pgfmathresult` as it will result in lots of warnings in your `.log` file.